# Dropdown Value in serach page remain after the search or refresh the page in laravel

Tags: laravel, dropdown

I tried to edit another person's code and I have to fix this small issue which is "Dropdown value will be remain even after refresh the page" and I am also new in laravel.

here is my view(I already tried some code)

```
             <b-field label="Industry" expanded>
                 <b-select required name="user_industry" expanded> 
                 @foreach ($users as $user)
                 <option value="{{ $user->id }}"  @if( session('forms.user')  == $user->id) selected="selected" @endif>{{ $user->user_industry }}</option>
                 @endforeach
                 <option value="Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing">Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing</option>
                 <option value="Mining">Mining</option>
                 </b-select>
              </b-field>
```

and this is my Controller:

```
public function main_network(Request $request) {
  session()->put('forms.user', $request->get('user_industry'));
  $user_industry = $request->has('user_industry') ? $request->get('user_industry') : null;
  $user_buisness = $request->has('user_business_name') ? $request->get('user_business_name') : null;

  $users = DNEUser::where('role_id',0)->where('user_status','accepted');

  if ($request->has('command') and $request->get('command') == 'page-search') {
    if ($user_industry != null) {
      $users = $users->where('user_industry',$user_industry);
    }
           if ($user_buisness != null) {
      $users = $users->where('user_business_name',$user_buisness);
    }
  }

  $users = $users->get();
  return $this->getView('dne.network',compact('page_title','page_description', 'users','user_industry','user_profession','user_buisness'));
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what will I have to put in @foreach in view page, I actually put '$users' because its already in my controller, so is that right?

Comment: you are to use old() method in laravel

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <b-field label="Industry" expanded>
                         <b-select required name="user_industry" expanded> 
                         @foreach ($users as $user)
                         <option value="{{ $user->id }}"  {{(old('user_industry') == $user->id ) ? "selected" : ""}}>{{ $user->user_industry }}</option>
                         @endforeach
                         <option value="Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing">Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing</option>

    <option value="Mining" {{(old('user_industry') == 'Mining') ? "selected" : ""}}>Mining</option>
                         </b-select>
                      </b-field>
```